# Directly put html code in a WebView (Android)

Tags: android, html, webview

While using WebView, we usually put a URL for it:

```
WebView.loadUrl(myURL);
```

but it is possible to put HTML code directly?? So that it will be in a logic that:

```
WebView.loadContent ( <html><head><script></script></head><body>....</body></html> );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Check out this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

```
 // OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: Thanks. you save my time :).

Answer (score 12):

```
 String yourhtmlpage = "<html><body>You scored <b>hello world</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourhtmlpage, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: What is the baseURL part for?

Comment: > Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy. The historyUrl is used for the history entry.

Answer (score 7):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
WebSettings settings = mDesc.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
mDesc.loadData(mDescText, "text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```