# Android: How to convert local string(html) to html page and display in the Webview

Tags: android, html, webview

The string contains the html page code. As the requirement, it better not to store in the file. How to represent it in the Webview?

Comment: What you have did so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you string contains the html page code then you can directly load in Webview like below.

```
webView.loadData(webData, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, /*Your HTML string*/, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

`String summary = "<html><body>Your <b>HTML</b> code.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);`

for more reference check this answer..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14002475/5362535